# How to save job logs into datasets using REXX

Tags: automation, mainframe, zos, rexx

I just got a task to check hundreds of jobs in SDSF.ST and save these job logs into specified datasets. I think I should automate this task using REXX but actually not familiar with the language. Having searched on Google, I still can't find a workable solution.

Anyone has any experience on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Rexx interface to SDSF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-sdsf-rexx-programming-language).  As this is a language with which you are unfamiliar, you will likely find use for the [programming reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=tsoe-zos-rexx-reference) and [user's guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=tsoe-zos-rexx-users-guide).  The [Rexx Language Association](http://www.rexxla.org/) has some [links](http://www.rexxla.org/links/) that may be helpful in getting up to speed, but Rexx was designed to be easy to learn and use so you shouldn't have too much trouble.

You could also use the [XDC](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=page-copying-joblog-data-set) line command if that's quicker than writing a program.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the observation that SDSF is really scanning/summarizing JES2 datasets.  So, is the requirement to store sysout datasets created by batch jobs?  if so, then it is possible to code the batch job so that it's sysout is stored.

if the requirement is to store the joblog itself, then get a JES2 manual and read-up on how JES manages joblogs (it has been awhile, so I have forgotten this info.).  After learning how JES2 manages its job logs, then there might be an obvious solution to saving them.

The above might have some advantages.  For example, what if a new job is added to the system that is needed to be saved?  Do you update your REXX code or a dataset of jobnames, or is the JCL for the job itself coded in a way to save the required sysout/joblog?

This makes a difference.  If someone has to update a list everytime a new production job is added, then this is time consuming and error prone.  If the JCL has to be coded in a specific way then it only has to be documented and it is easy for managers to say "code production jobs in a such-and-so fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this numerous times and developed a generalized REXX exec to do this - find it at https://github.com/lbdyck/sdsfxdd

```
%sdsfxdd JOBname(jobname(jobid)) +
   STEPname(stepname) +
   DDname(ddname) +
   HLQ(high-level-qualifier) +
   QUALifier(qualifier) +
   SUFfix(suffix) +
   LISt(list) +
   OWNer(owner) +
   SYStem(sys) +
   DATE(date)
```